# Cambio d fecha y hora android

Tags: android

Alguien sabe como podría saber cuando alguien ha cambiado la fecha y la hora de un movil android. Es dicir obtener algun log o mostrar alguna notificación??
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola ScorpJr, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo con un `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class ReceiverFechaHora extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "cambio fecha/hora", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Logica del negocio
    }
}
```

y lo registras en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` con el filter `android.intent.action.TIME_SET`

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ReceiverFechaHora">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: No es bueno responder a estas preguntas, sin ver que el usuario a buscado un avance, esperando que que realicen su trabajo ... No es apoyado por la comunidad este tipo de preguntas de "opinión"